# TypeScript Question, case switch returns unexpected type

Tags: typescript

Can anyone explain me this (see comment in the code section)?

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3&ssl=19&ssc=35&pln=19&pc=84#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwJ4BsD2cAmAcgK4C2ARtMgN4BQyyA1hBgFzIBEAghwNz3J8cMHHYgylKPwC%20tWqEixEKdNjz4AymCigA5jQHM2nAEJ8BQkewDO2vTLkLo8JMgCqAB0sQtwiFwQwYBwQAwYPTFwCdlUoogkqAB80SPUtHRBdB1oEENtkAHcACz8ANyoAXmQACkQgkPZPb19IAPqQAEoxBKhkCoA%20MORckHzqJhZkaT7kOuCQADoItQJ%20BmsC4DAEIpqjDqGGBDhrFG4OVgEGBigIMGIoULmQpdSCBcs4XmQAeh-kADqRQwyGA1mQYCKYOQtgy%20mS4goVDgIHwyBAODA6J6AH5kIA%20DcAKLtXQQQeDELBgS7Xa63e6PZAARjWU1o0n4tCAA)

```ts
interface PayloadNumber {
  key: "A";
  data: number;
}

interface PayloadString {
  key: "B";
  data: string;
}

interface UpdateStateAction {
  payload: PayloadNumber | PayloadString;
}

const whatever = (action: UpdateStateAction): number => {
  const { key } = action.payload;
  switch (key) {
    case "A":
      return action.payload.data; // Why is this string | number and not number? 
    default:
      return 1;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is destructuring

```
const { key } = action.payload;
// or even
const key = action.payload.key;
```

We're isolating `key` in `PayloadNumber | PayloadString`.

Since we're only looking at `key` the only inference typescript can make is whether `key` is `"A"` or `"B"`.

Typescript can't possibly make inferences about `action.payload.data` because it has no idea you're trying to determine it's type via `key`.

You can do two things, either

```
const whatever = (action: UpdateStateAction): number => {
  switch (action.payload.key) {
    case 'A':
      return action.payload.data;
    default:
      return 1;
  }
};
```

or

```
const whatever = (action: UpdateStateAction): number => {
  const p = action.payload;
  switch (p.key) {
    case 'A':
      return p.data;
    default:
      return 1;
  }
};
```

You'll see that `action.payload.data` now has the correct typing. You can see in both cases we're referencing the whole `payload` type instead of just `key` in `payload`.

Comment: Wow. This totally makes sense now. Thank you so much. Great explanation!